# How to use priority queues in Scala?

Tags: scala, tuples, priority-queue, scala-collections

I am trying to implement A* search in Scala (version 2.10), but I've ran into a brick wall - I can't figure out how to use Scala's Priority Queue.

I have a set of squares, represented by `(Int, Int)`s, and I need to insert them with priorities represented by `Int`s. In Python you just have a list of key, value pairs and use the heapq functions to sort it.

So how do you do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is actually [pre-defined lexicographical order for tuples](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/math/Ordering.scala#L358) -- [but you need to import it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102393/how-to-lexicographically-compare-scala-tuples):

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
```

Moreover, you can define your own ordering.
Suppose I want to arrange tuples, based on the difference between first and second members of the tuple:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue
//  import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

scala> def diff(t2: (Int,Int)) = math.abs(t2._1 - t2._2)
// diff: (t2: (Int, Int))Int

scala> val x = new PriorityQueue[(Int, Int)]()(Ordering.by(diff))
// x: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[(Int, Int)] = PriorityQueue()

scala> x.enqueue(1 -> 1)

scala> x.enqueue(1 -> 2)

scala> x.enqueue(1 -> 3)

scala> x.enqueue(1 -> 4)

scala> x.enqueue(1 -> 0)

scala> x
// res5: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[(Int, Int)] = PriorityQueue((1,4), (1,3), (1,2), (1,1), (1,0))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to import `scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._` before but I missed a period.

Comment: @Antimony please, see edit. I've misguided you with += operation, you have to use `.enqueue`

Answer (score -1):

Indeed, there is no implicit ordering on pairs of integers (a, b). What would it be? Perhaps they are both positive and you can use (a - 1.0/b)? Or they are not, and you can use, what, (a + atan(b/pi))? If you have an ordering in mind, you can consider wrapping your pairs in a type that has your ordering.

Comment: Well the natural ordering is lexicographical, which is what C++ and Python do. Silly me for assuming Scala is at least as functional as C++.

Comment: @Antimony: Just to clarify: The C++ language and its standard libraries themselves contain this ordering?