# Apache Spark: distinct doesnt work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my code example:

```
 case class Person(name:String,tel:String){
        def equals(that:Person):Boolean = that.name == this.name && this.tel == that.tel}

 val persons = Array(Person("peter","139"),Person("peter","139"),Person("john","111"))
 sc.parallelize(persons).distinct.collect
```

It returns

```
 res34: Array[Person] = Array(Person(john,111), Person(peter,139), Person(peter,139))
```

Why distinct doesn't work?I want the result as Person("john",111),Person("peter",139)

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with "peter" not being the same as "perter"?

Comment: How much time did you spend looking into the problem before posting it? What do you expect as result of this test?

Comment: Flagged for closing as this appears to be caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: The typo was unfortunate while writing the question. I tried on Spark this and indeed is an issue. I reverted my earlier -1

Comment: @kviiri this is a real (and rather puzzling) issue. Could you revert the close vote?

Comment: @maasg I agree this is peculiar, kviiri doesn't have enough rep to close vote though so it wasn't him

Comment: I investigated further in the source code and the root cause is that case clases do not seem to work as keys in Spark. I've created a discussion on the mailing list: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Using-case-classes-as-keys-does-not-seem-to-work-td10407.html

Comment: FYI - I created a bug against Spark 1.0.0 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2620

Comment: What happens if you don't write your own equals method?? - after all you have no need to do so. Just a shot in the dark as a workaround.

Comment: @maasg, I'm sorry but at the time I flagged it there really was a typo and the issue was fundamentally different.

Comment: (Also, it appears that I can't retract any flags, which is a rather annoying "feature" of the site)

Answer (score 1):

Extending further from the observation of @aaronman, there is a workaround for this issue.
On the RDD, there're two definitions for `distinct`:

```
 /**
   * Return a new RDD containing the distinct elements in this RDD.
   */
  def distinct(numPartitions: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T] = null): RDD[T] =
    map(x => (x, null)).reduceByKey((x, y) => x, numPartitions).map(_._1)

  /**
   * Return a new RDD containing the distinct elements in this RDD.
   */
  def distinct(): RDD[T] = distinct(partitions.size)
```

It's apparent from the signature of the first `distinct` that there must be an implicit ordering of the elements and it's assumed null if absent, which is what the short version `.distinct()` does.

There's no default implicit ordering for case classes, but it's easy to implement one:

```
case class Person(name:String,tel:String) extends Ordered[Person] {
  def compare(that: Person): Int = this.name compare that.name
}
```

Now, trying the same example delivers the expected results (note that I'm comparing names):

```
val ps5 = Array(Person("peter","138"),Person("peter","55"),Person("john","138"))
sc.parallelize(ps5).distinct.collect

res: Array[P5] = Array(P5(john,111), P5(peter,139))
```

Note that case classes already implement `equals` and `hashCode`, so the impl on the provided example is unnecessary and also incorrect. The correct signature for `equals` is: `equals(arg0: Any): Boolean` -- BTW, I first thought that the issue had to do with the incorrect equals signature, which sent me looking in the wrong path.

Comment: In spark-shell 1.0,I follow every step from your guiding,but return   `res2: Array[Person] = Array(Person(john,138), Person(peter,138), Person(peter,55))`

Comment: @MrQuestion what exact version of Spark do you use? I'll try again on whatever you're using.

Comment: I have tried it with spark 1.0.0 and 1.0.1,neither of them works

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was related to object equality, as mentioned by Martin Odersky in Programming in Scala (chapter 30), although I have a normal class (not a case class). For a correct equality test, you must re-define (override) hashCode() if you have a custom equals(). Also you need to have a canEqual() method for 100% correctness. I haven't looked at the implementation details of an RDD, but since it is a collection, probably it uses some complex/parallel variation of a HashSet or other hash-based data structure for comparing objects and ensuring distinctness.

Declaring hashSet(), equals(), canEqual(), and compare() methods solved my problem:

```
override def hashCode(): Int = {
  41 * (41 + name.hashCode) + tel.hashCode
}

override def equals(other: Any) = other match {
  case other: Person =>
    (other canEqual this) &&
    (this.name == other.name) && (this.tel == other.tel)
  case _ =>
    false
}

def canEqual(other: Any) = other.isInstanceOf[Person]

def compare(that: Person): Int = {
  this.name compare that.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out this is a bug in spark 1.0.0. My theory as to where it is coming from is that if you look at the diff of 1.0.0 to 9.0 you see

```
-  def repartition(numPartitions: Int): RDD[T] = {
+  def repartition(numPartitions: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T] = null): RDD[T] = {
```

And if you run

```
case class A(i:Int)
implicitly[Ordering[A]]
```

You get an error

```
<console>:13: error: No implicit Ordering defined for A.
              implicitly[Ordering[A]]
```

So I think the workaround is define an implicit ordering for a the case class, unfortunately I'm not a scala expert but this [answer seems to do it correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345030/easy-idiomatic-way-to-define-ordering-for-a-simple-case-class)

Comment: @MrQuestion honestly this is just a guess, I'm not fully sure how implicit resolution works in scala