# Scala Implicit Ordering

Tags: scala, implicit

Is there a way for me to define the same implicit ordering for two different classes?

I tried to do something along the following lines but it doesn't detect the ordering.

```
abstract class Common
case class A extends Common
case class B extends Common

implicit val KeyOrdering = new Ordering[Common] {
    override def compare(x: Common, y: Common): Int = {
      x.toString.compareTo(y.toString)
   }
}
```

Comment: `extends` is a reserved keyword and not a type. Do you mean `Common`?

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Yea, I'm also not sure why this won't work. `List(A(), B()).sorted` says that no implicit ordering can be found, yet explicitly `List(A(), B()).sorted(KeyOrdering)` works.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As noted by @ntn, the inferred type of your list - the least upper bound of its two elements - is `Product with Serializable with Common`. As `scala.Ordering` is not contravariant on its type parameter, implicit resolution fails because it does not hold that `Ordering[Common] <: Ordering[Product with Serializable with Common]`.

You can work around this by writing the implicit ordering so that it always has the exact type of the implicit parameter under consideration:

```
abstract class Common
case class A() extends Common
case class B() extends Common

object Common {
  implicit def ordering[A <: Common]: Ordering[A] = new Ordering[A] {
    override def compare(x: A, y: A): Int = {
      x.toString.compareTo(y.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

Or for concision:

```
object Common {
  implicit def ordering[A <: Common]: Ordering[A] = Ordering.by(_.toString)
}
```

Comment: I see by your other answer that you are an expert.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345030/easy-idiomatic-way-to-define-ordering-for-a-simple-case-class

Comment: Speaking of which, I have updated that answer with a note about this specific issue.

Comment: The `Ordering` trait has a single abstract method to implement: the `compare` function. This is known as a Single Abstract Method (SAM) type.

Since Scala 2.12 and the introduction of lambda syntax for SAM types, the implementation in the first example can be elegantly simplified to:

`implicit def ordering[A <: Common]: Ordering[A] = (x: A, y: A) => x.toString.compareTo(y.toString)`

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the case class for A and B (or even only for one of them), then it works.
For `List(A(), B()).sorted`, it fails to find an `Ordering` for `Product with Serializable with C`, as the base class for A and B is Product with C (due to A and B being both case classes).

If you are creating a list with elements of two different base types, I assume you want a list of type `List[C]`, in which you can declare the elements before using them (or get them from some function which returns type `C`.

```
val a: C = A()
val b: C = B()
List(a,b).sorted
```