# When implicit def tupleOrderingDesc:Ordering[Tuple2[String,Int]] will be triggered

Tags: scala

When I read code, I found below function, this is an implicit function, but seems there is no input for this function. Always, the implicit function will be like this:
implicit def int2Fraction(n: Int) = Fraction(n, 1)
this function will transfer Int to Fraction.
But for below code how it works? When the implicit conversion happens?

```
implicit def tupleOrderingDesc:Ordering[Tuple2[String,Int]] = {
      new Ordering[Tuple2[String, Int]] {
        override def compare(x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int)): Int = {
          if (y._1.compare(x._1) == 0) y._2.compare(x._2)
          else y._1.compare(x._1)
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicits (types, functions) are applied as soon as a function is called which has this type of implicit as implicit parameter. So the above will be applied when an Ordering of the specified type Tuple2[String,Int] is needed, e.g when comparing,sorting.

More detailed discussion can be found here:
[Easy idiomatic way to define Ordering for a simple case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345030/easy-idiomatic-way-to-define-ordering-for-a-simple-case-class)

and on implicits in general, including Ordering:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html

Comment: Thank you awagen. I understand this case now.