# scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue: Comparing with 2 or more attributes of a case class

Tags: scala, comparator, priority-queue

This question [Easy idiomatic way to define Ordering for a simple case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345030/easy-idiomatic-way-to-define-ordering-for-a-simple-case-class) looks similar but not same. This question is more related to priority queue.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

  case class Task(prio: Int, text: String, jobPriority:Int)
    extends Ordered[Task] {
    def compare(that: Task) = that.prio compare this.prio
   // def compare(x: Task, y: Task) = y.prio compare this.prio //&&  y.jobPriority compare this.jobPriority

  }

  //test
  var q: mutable.PriorityQueue[Task] = PriorityQueue[Task]() ++ Seq(Task(3, "Clear drains",1), Task(4, "Feed cat",2),
    Task(5, "Make tea",9), Task(1, "Solve RC tasks",5), Task(2, "Tax return",5))
  while (q.nonEmpty) println(q dequeue)
```

is giving me this output :

```
Task(1,Solve RC tasks,5)
Task(2,Tax return,5)
Task(3,Clear drains,1)
Task(4,Feed cat,2)
Task(5,Make tea,9)
```

now I want to consider `jobPriority` as well while doing comparison. just like  custom java comparator which compares multiple attributes.

*Is there any way in scala to achieve this ?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy idiomatic way to define Ordering for a simple case class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345030/easy-idiomatic-way-to-define-ordering-for-a-simple-case-class)

Comment: It is still a duplicate. Based on the answer you have accepted, the linked question is an exact answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
case class Task(prio: Int, text: String, jobPriority:Int)
    extends Ordered[Task] {
    def prioCompare(that: Task) = that.prio compare this.prio
    def jobPriorityCompare(that: Task) = that.jobPriority compare this.jobPriority
    def compare(that: Task) = {
      val prioC = prioCompare(that)

      if(prioC == 0) jobPriorityCompare(that) else prioC
    }

  }

  //test
  var q: mutable.PriorityQueue[Task] = PriorityQueue[Task]() ++ Seq(Task(3, "Clear drains",6), Task(4, "Feed cat",2),
    Task(5, "Make tea",9), Task(1, "Solve RC tasks",5), Task(3, "Tax return",5))
  while (q.nonEmpty) println(q dequeue)

/* Output
Task(1,Solve RC tasks,5)
Task(3,Tax return,5)
Task(3,Clear drains,6)
Task(4,Feed cat,2)
Task(5,Make tea,9)
*/
```

Comment: This may work. but the linked question provides a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

comparing with tuple :

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

  case class Task(prio: Int, text: String, jobPrio: Int)
    extends Ordered[Task] {

    import scala.math.Ordered.orderingToOrdered

    def compare(that: Task) = (that.prio, that.jobPrio) compare(this.prio, this.jobPrio)

  }

  //test
  var q: mutable.PriorityQueue[Task] = PriorityQueue[Task]() ++ Seq(Task(3, "Clear drains", 1), Task(4, "Feed cat", 2),
    Task(5, "Make tea", 9), Task(1, "Solve RC tasks", 5), Task(2, "Tax return", 5))
  while (q.nonEmpty) println(q dequeue)
```

---

Result :

```
Task(1,Solve RC tasks,5)
Task(2,Tax return,5)
Task(3,Clear drains,1)
Task(4,Feed cat,2)
Task(5,Make tea,9)
```